# Issues with HTML modals, do not display

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had some troubles with some HTML modals. I made a query from a database and I want the result to be displayed with a modal in the front end.

Everything is good in the beginning when only the ID should be displayed in a button. But when I click on one, only the first one in the row opens, the rest of them are not corresponding.

As I know, when you want to show some more information about a specific ID, as in my situation couple more columns, that is possible with anchors `<a>` where the preferable information can be displayed through a new .php file and is selected from the others by the link.

Is there any way that I can do the same, maybe by specifying the ID in every button, then the right modal with the right information pops up?

Here is the code:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)): ?> 
    <button>
        <h2>ID:</h2>
        <span>
            <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        </span> 
    </button>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span> 
            <h2>ΙD:</h2> 
            <span>
                <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
            </span> 
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-body"> 
            <ul> 
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                    </span>
                </li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <?php echo $row['number']; ?>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And the code for opening the modals:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a Bootstrap modal -- is that right? Typically you'd want to launch your modal through `data-target="#ID"`. Could you please post the code that launches your modals are well?

Comment: Sure my bad!
Could you please explain to me a little more because I didn't understand how I can make that work

Comment: `document.getElementById('myModal');` 1) This will only ever target exactly 1 modal, but your code is looping and generating lots of modals. 2) your code doesn't show any elements with `id="myModal"` anyway, so it won't open anything.

Comment: @ADyson so with bootstrap that should work or are there more JavaScript functions that are needed?

Comment: well in our discussion on your other question i suggested you to generate only one modal in your HTML, and then populate it on-demand with the correct data. So you'd need to a) move the modal HTML out of your look and give it an ID, b) put some data-attributes on each button to store the related name and number fields for that ID), c) handle the button's click event and populate the right parts of the modal with the values from the clicked button's data-atttributes, then show the modal. Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals as well.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to type up and test a whole answer right now. If I have time later, and you're still stuck, I'll try and do so. Do you also use jQuery?

Comment: Sure, I will wait because I haven't made it work. No I don't use jQuery

Comment: in order to use Bootstrap's modals you need jQuery. Otherwise you'll be getting errors (in the Console of your browser's Developer Tools, I mean) if you try it in the way Hafeez suggested below, and the modal won't open. The error will be telling you that you need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using Bootstrap, you can use these codes below

For the button to open modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#try">Open Modal</button>
```

Inside of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="try" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="form">
            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <h3>Hi</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <button type="button" class="close mr-4" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't fix it, now it's not even opening the first modal

Comment: @LeoBl is Bootstrap running in your page? What version?

Comment: @ADyson yes, 3.3.7

Comment: This example is a bit faulty. But the principle is sound. Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/n06zscjq/1/ There was a div missing, and also the button tag is not closed properly.

Comment: Hafeez please check your code properly before posting. Thanks.